# Calculate migration timing based on the segclust function

Tags: r, migration

I'm working on bird migration and for my project I have to you the function "segclust" in order to identify the migration period, more specifically beginning and end date of migration.

To do so, I'm working on data set at the individual level for each year of tagging using variation in latitude and longitude. However, everytime I'm running my script I get the same error.

```
segclust(tab_indY,lmin=100, Kmax = 5,seg.var=c("Lat"), nclust = 3, subsample = 12, scale.variable =F)
```

subsample = 12 --> one point every hour (since original data subsampled to 1loc/5min)
nclust = 3 --> to delimitate 3 periods (breeding, wintering and migrations)
Kmax = 5 --> conrresponding to every blocks of a typical latitude variation during a year

I get the following error which make sense since the point during breeding season and wintering are really close to each other since the individual is not moving far.

```
"Error in FUN(X[[i]], ...) : tation without clustering
  Problem with a segment starting at point 1787 (once subsampled) and ending at point 1791. (or maybe after also). Please check if the segment 
                      has a potentially very low variance 
                      compared to the rest of the serie. 
                      This could happen if there are interpolations of
                      trajectories or if data have not been properly cleaned
                      (e.g. motionless gps points due to a fallen devices).
                      The algorithm cannot work with 
                      series of (near-)identical points."
```

I don't know to handle this problem if you could help me I would really appreciate

Thanks in advance.

Comment: `segclust` is not a base R function. When using functions that are not base R functions please start the scripts with a call to `library(pkgname)` in order to load the packages needed.